# How to run ant by using maven for selenium junit to generate test reports

Tags: maven, ant, selenium-webdriver, junit4

Hi am trying to run testsuite which has implemented to by using JUNIT,ANT,MAVEN configuration.

The below pom.xml I have created but ... testsuites are not running... if I run maven.

I am runnning like this by using command line

mvn antrun:run

Should I use any other commands or am i missing any thing in pom.xml ? that are the commands to run the testsuite ?

Comment: Cltr+K and paste your code. It will let you copy your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for inconvenience my stackoverflow is not allowing to paste full code of pom.xml

Comment: I am getting this error Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ms.dart</groupId>
  <artifactId>dart-selenium-testing</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>dart-selenium-testing</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>